# Generate JSON from Java for Flexigrid using json-simple libary

Tags: java, json, class, servlets, flexigrid

Given the following expected JSON format, I am trying to generate JSON using Java:

```
{
  "stat": "ok",
  "page": 1,
  "total": 100,
  "rows": [
     {
       "id":"1",
       "cell":[
         "content of column 1",
         "content of column 2",
         "content of column 3",
         "content of column 4", 
         "content of column 5",
         "content of column 6",
         "content of column 7",
         "content of column 8",
         "content of column 9"
       ]
    },  
     {
       "id":"2",
       "cell":[
         "content of column 1",
         "content of column 2",
         "content of column 3",
         "content of column 4", 
         "content of column 5",
         "content of column 6",
         "content of column 7",
         "content of column 8",
         "content of column 9"
       ]
    },
```

I have thus far written the following code which is close in some regard, but it does not contain logic to supported nested objects. I find this difficult, because the code required to represent a JSON object uses a object that is of a HashMap type which requires unique keys. So where I need to have multiple "id" entries, I can only have one hashmap key entered with id. I also tried with google / Guava multimap, but there is a limitation in trying to cast or mix the JSON library and google implementation at the same time.

The below code generates this as the output:

```
{
  "total": "100",
  "page": "1",
  "stat": "ok",
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "cell": [
        "test which represents one column's content",
        "test, which contains 2nd column's data"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which you can see from above, would be close but incorrect because it will only contain 1 x row and cell.

```
public class GenerateJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONArray cell = new JSONArray();
        cell.add("test which represents one column's content");
        cell.add("test, which contains 2nd column's data");

        JSONObject ids = new JSONObject();
        ids.put("id", "1");
        ids.put("cell",cell);

        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap(ids);

        JSONArray rows = new JSONArray();
        rows.add(ids);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("stat","ok");
        obj.put("total","100");
        obj.put("page","1");
        obj.put("rows",rows);

        System.out.println(obj);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying below code this might work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject obj = null;

    JSONArray cellArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray cellArray1 = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("id", i);
        obj.put("cell", "contecnt 1, content 2, content 3");

        cellArray.put(obj);
    }

    JSONObject responseData = new org.json.JSONObject();

    responseData.put("rows", cellArray);

//      System.out.println(responseData);

    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();

    obj1.put("stat", "ok");
    obj1.put("total", "100");
    obj1.put("page", 1);
    obj1.put("rows", responseData);

    cellArray1.put(obj1);

    JSONObject response = new org.json.JSONObject();

    response.put("data", cellArray1);

    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Output:

```
{"data":[{"total":"100","page":1,"stat":"ok",
"rows":
{"rows":[
  {"id":0,
  "cell":"contecnt 1, content 2, content 3"},

  {"id":1,
  "cell":"contecnt 1, content 2, content 3"}
 ]}
}]}
```

Comment: I don't think this resolves the dilemma I am facing.  In pseudo-summary of what we are trying to produce,  we must have a Cell Array contained inside an object, which is contained inside a rows array, which is contained inside an object. {
  "total": "100",
  "page": "1",
  "stat": "ok",
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "cell": [
        "test which represents one column's content",
        "test, which contains 2nd column's data"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Can you extend your example to show 2 x rows ( records) , which in turn contain 2 x sample cells ( columns of data).  ?

Comment: @RaananIkar see if this output can satisfy your condition.

Comment: This is closer and I see where you were going with this 2nd update. I will try as well with a custom class, which was what I attempted first before reverting back to strictly the library. However the data must match exactly the following in terms of the expected output: {
  "stat": "ok",
  "page": 1,
  "total": 1,
  "rows": [
     {
       "id":"1",
       "cell":[
         "content of column 1",
         "content of column 2" 
       ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: As you can see, we must include stat, page, total, then contain rows, where inside this, for each row, there is an ID with the row position, and then the record labeled cell, and inside this each column's data.  The only text or labels expected outside of the values I must provide are stat, page, total, rows, id, and cell.  Adding "data" or prefixing "rows" numerous times would not work.  However I think the custom class is what is necessary. I have tried using a vector as well, but I think class is what I will try like in your example.

Comment: @RaananIkar I think if you try nested json then you can achieve what exactly you are looking for. Like rows as inner json and outer json as your total,page etc.

Comment: @RaananIkar I have done changes in code see if this is ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as a two step process if thats not a problem.

1) generate the xml equivalent of json you want in java using the Document builder.

2)converting xml into its json equivalent is quite easy then...
hope this helps!