# Jackson JSON schema date

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I would like to generate a JSON **schema** of a class with a java.util.Date field.
For fields with type Date I am getting:

"fieldName" :   {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "UTC_MILLISEC"
    }

What i would like is something like:

"fieldName" :{ "type": "string", "format": "date-time" }

I would like this configuration to be global for all POJOS and not only for a specific POJO.
So, an annotation on a specific class will not help me.

Thanks!

Comment: See if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366924/generate-json-from-java-for-flexigrid-using-json-simple-libary/25367231#25367231) can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to output the date as a string then you should disable the configuration `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` on your `OjectMapper` instances. Then every Date object which is converted will be written as a string. See [this link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features#datatype-specific-serialization) for more information on the Serialisation features.

Comment: See Alexey's example on how to actually generate the schema output once you have the correct settings.

Answer (score 5):

This is just an example for [the Dennis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25367776/3537858) demonstrating that `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` is actually taking into account by [the Jackson schema generator](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema).

```
public class JacksonSchema1 {

    public static class Bean {
        public String name;
        public Date date;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
        mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(mapper.constructType(Bean.class), visitor);
        JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "date" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "format" : "DATE_TIME"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to answer the part of the question about how to generate the schema. Thanks very much for including this information.

Answer (score 2):

Jackson has a nifty custom `JsonSerializer` class that you can extend. You basically just create a new class that extends `JsonSerializer<Date>` and override the `serialize` method.

Heres an example.

```
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
  @Override
  public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      jgen.writeStartObject();
      jgen.writeStringField("format", "date-time");
      jgen.writeStringField("type", "string");
      jgen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

Next we need to register the serializer with the `ObjectMapper` being used.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Date.class, new DateSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

That should give you the JsonSerialization that you are looking for. The only thing you will have to do is modify the serializer so that it is serializing the correct values.

Comment: How is this an answer to a question about _schema_?